# Probability of a sample size

Tags: probability, statistics

At a fertilizer company, 20% of the bags coming off of the line are below the advertised label weight(underweight). If a random sample of fertilizer bags is taken and each bag is weighed until $1$ underweight bag is found, what's the probability that the sample size taken is going to be exactly 3?

My initial thought was to take a binomial distribution with of $B(.2, 2, 0) \cdot B(.2,1,1)$, but that's just guesswork on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the Geometric distribution. It describes the probability of needinf x Bernouilli trials before the first succes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: That definitely seems right.  The only thing that worries me is that we haven't studied that in our class.

Answer (score 1):

Since the geometric distribution is apparently off-limits, we can also approach it as follows (though this is effectively the approach yielding the geometric distribution, which you can at least use to check your answer).

Consider the following two probabilities:

- The first two bags are not underweight
- The first three bags are not underweight

Can you extract the probability that the third bag is underweight?

---

**Edit:** Also compare this with your initial guess.